# Screen Flicker in Vista

Tags: windows-vista

I noticed everytime my dell inspiron 1420 wakes up from sleep the screen will flicker a lot. some times violently. I'm not sure what the problem is. I have disabled tmm but it didn't fix the flickers. Does anyone have a solution?

Here's my spec:

```
Dell Inspiron 1420
4GB RAM
Intel Core 2 Duo T5750
Nvidia Geforce 8400MS
Windows Vista 32bit
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be your refresh rate set to a value that is not recommended for your monitor. After a while you might not notice it as much, but will when it first starts?

Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

reseat the ram.  I had the same problem. I removed one stick and the flicker was gone. After i replaced the ram no more problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen issues with screen flickering and Vista before. This problems were happening on desktops that were running an Asus Motherboard with an AMD chipset, with or without additional graphics card. Regardless of what type of graphics driver I installed, the screen would always flicker rather randomly. The only thing that helped in this case was a BIOS upgrade.

Apparently, the BIOS that originally came with the mother didn't fully support Vista regardless of it saying it did.

Not sure if it's possible for you to update the bios on your laptop, but that could be the problem.

It could also be a hardware issue, does this happen with other OS's running (you could try a Linux Live CD and see if it still happens then). If that's the case, then the wire connecting the LCD on your laptop could be going out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a theory: when your Vista PC goes to sleep (as opposed to hibernate or hybrid sleep), everything is still active in RAM but put into a low power standby mode. When the PC wakes up, everything comes back, and the graphics display needs to be turned back on. I believe going to sleep and coming back is the responsibility of the BIOS, and where the display is involved too, the graphics card driver.

When your graphics card goes to sleep, your BIOS and your graphics card driver are supposed to be smart about it. When waking up, the least clean way to restart the graphics card would be to reset the card and then load up every saved setting one by one. This is the least clean because every setting change on the card while it shuts down, starts up, changes resolutions, etc. is going to make a little disturbance on the video output. It's possible this is what your graphics card is doing when you see all that flickering. The way the system is supposed to work is that your graphics card supports some kind of low power mode with rapid restore, and your BIOS and graphics card driver is supposed to know how to use it to wake up from the sleep state with a minimal delay and flickering.

The bottom line is that the excessive flickering may be the fault of your BIOS or the card's graphics driver, and you might want to see if there are any updates for those.